# Html5 tr with file attribute

Tags: html, attributes, html5-audio

I saw a piece of code like this:

```
var pl = document.createElement('tr');
...
pl.file = f;
pl.onclick = function(e){
    if(e && e.button == 1){
        pl.parentNode.removeChild(pl);
    }else{
        var url;
        if(window.createObjectURL){
            url = window.createObjectURL(f)
        }else if(window.createBlobURL){
            url = window.createBlobURL(f)
        }else if(window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL){
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(f)
        }else if(window.webkitURL && window.webkitURL.createObjectURL){
            url = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(f)
        }                      
        $("player").src = url;
        $("player").play();
    }
}
```

It's for a audio player. And I was thinking if tr element have a file attribute? I was searched the internet but got nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question. I think pl.file is just creating a dynamic member.

Comment: I think, pl is a tr element that was dynamically created by the script.

Comment: yeah, what's the question?  You can create pl.HereIAm = "Here I am" and then alert(pl.HereIAm);  That's the dynamic nature of JavaScript at work.

Comment: OH! I see, you mean attributes can be customize even it's not in the W3C attribute list, in javascript!!thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `<tr>` element does not have a `file` attribute. This means you shouldn't write the following (invalid) HTML:

```
<tr file="http://example.com/file.txt">
```

You can do something very close to that in HTML5 using `data-file` as the attribute's name, then it's valid.

```
<tr data-file="http://example.com/file.txt">
```

But you don't have that on your markup (presumably), you're just taking a JavaScript object that represents that `<tr>`, and adding it a property – *not an attribute*. To manipulate an actual attribute (like `data-file`), you'd have to use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

Comment: That's what I thought he wanted at first too, but he said he found the code.  He's not writing it.

Comment: Oh, I thought attribute of a tag is limited by the W3C attribute list. So I was suffering by this file attribute.